# Why is the space of Riemannian metric on a manifold an open set with respect to the Sobolev class of symmetric $0,2$ tensors?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $H^s(T^2_0M)$ be the Sobolev class of symmetric $0,2$ tensors defined by the class of $0,2$ tensors whose derivatives up to order $s$ exist in the sense of distributions and are square integrable. Since it is a vector space, it can be identified as $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, equipped with usual topology.

Let $\mathcal{M}^s$ be the subset of $H^s(T^2_0M)$ consisting of Riemannian metrics on $M$. How can I show that it is an open set in $H^s(T^2_0M)$? The usual approach is to construct continuous map whose preimage of some open set in the range of the function is $\mathcal{M}^s$. However, I have no idea how to construct such a map.

Comment: Two things: note that your Sobolev space is not a finite dimensional one, so it is not isomorphic to any $\mathbb{R}^n$. Second, as far as I remember Riemannian metrics are smooth (or at least continuous), so I do not think there would be any Sobolev space where they would be open...

Comment: Here Riemannian metrics are assumed to be in the Sobolev space (i.e. those positive definite elements in the space).

Comment: I think $s$ needs to satisfy at least $s>\frac{n}2$. Also, is $M$ bounded?